# Visualizing my data with python using seaborn catplot

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I have this DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

I'd like to generate a plot that shows 3 categories "Product": CX, RX, TX, within each one it has the "Type": CX, Low, Medium High. It looks like seaborn catplot would do what I want but I can't seem to make it work.

Something like this:

[image: desired output]